# Generate of all drawable sizes from one (large) image automatcly

Tags: android, automation, drawable

I am investing some time doing drawables for an Android project and I am looking for alternatives.

Currently I do them on Adobe Illustrator and with some drawables I can use [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com) (e.g. drawables for the action menu). The problem with Android Asset Studio is the lack of possibilities to use my own color (we can only use white/black colors).

I wanted something like Android Asset Studio where I can give him a HD image and he creates all drawable sizes. Is that possible?

Another option could be a program/script that could allow me to say "I want to scale to these resolutions" and he does it for all images.

Comment: MS Paint! :P  Try out a free image editor like Paint.net. You can resize the images yourself.

Comment: I can resize images. That is not the problem. I just wanted a more optimal way to do this. It would save some time just to generate all drawables from a single image. Like Android Asset Studio saved time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [batch resizer](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch%20resize%20images), but without knowing what you're working with, it's hard to give a recommendation. For instance, you can use both Photoshop and Gimp for it. I believe Gimp will require a plugin, while Photoshop has the script built-in.

Comment: As I said I am working with Adobe Illustrator. Although a script could do that I was looking for something that could provide me a preview of the final resizes (like Android Asset Studio).